# Quickest way to populate a table in MySQL via phymyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have about 8000 records in an Excel file and wish to add them to a MySQL table. I need to know the quickest way to populate the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the Excel worksheet as a .CSV file, and use the MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement to read the .CSV file and insert rows to a table. That's the quickest.